# Почему в clang нет логики для разворачивания итераторов?

Tags: c++

В MSVC активно используется функция `_STD _Get_unwrapped()`, которая итератор превращает в указатель. Такой подход реализован у них во всех функциях, которые работают по диапазону итераторов. Например, вот так выглядит функция `set_intersection` (часть кода опущена).

```
template<class _InIt1,
    class _InIt2,
    class _OutIt,
    class _Pr> inline
    _OutIt set_intersection(_InIt1 _First1, _InIt1 _Last1,
        _InIt2 _First2, _InIt2 _Last2, _OutIt _Dest, _Pr _Pred)
    {   // AND sets [_First1, _Last1) and [_First2, _Last2), using _Pred
    auto      _UFirst1 = _Get_unwrapped(_First1);
    const auto _ULast1 = _Get_unwrapped(_Last1);
    auto      _UFirst2 = _Get_unwrapped(_First2);
    const auto _ULast2 = _Get_unwrapped(_Last2);
    auto        _UDest = _Get_unwrapped_unverified(_Dest);

    while (_UFirst1 != _ULast1 && _UFirst2 != _ULast2)
        {
        if (_DEBUG_LT_PRED(_Pred, *_UFirst1, *_UFirst2))
            {
            ++_UFirst1;
            }
        else if (_Pred(*_UFirst2, *_UFirst1))
            {
            ++_UFirst2;
            }
        else
            {
            *_UDest = *_UFirst1;
            ++_UDest;
            ++_UFirst1;
            ++_UFirst2;
            }
        }

    _Seek_wrapped(_Dest, _UDest);
    return (_Dest);
    }
```

Но [в исходниках clang](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/main/libcxx/include/__algorithm/set_intersection.h) я не нашел ничего подобного, там все эти функции работают напрямую с итераторами.

```
template <class _Compare, class _InputIterator1, class _InputIterator2, class _OutputIterator>
_LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX17 _OutputIterator
__set_intersection(_InputIterator1 __first1, _InputIterator1 __last1,
                   _InputIterator2 __first2, _InputIterator2 __last2, _OutputIterator __result, _Compare __comp)
{
    while (__first1 != __last1 && __first2 != __last2)
    {
        if (__comp(*__first1, *__first2))
            ++__first1;
        else
        {
            if (!__comp(*__first2, *__first1))
            {
                *__result = *__first1;
                ++__result;
                ++__first1;
            }
            ++__first2;
        }
    }
    return __result;
}
```

---

Почему они не используют указатели вместо итераторов? Это же большой прирост в скорости.

Comment: Так может он оптимизациями компилятора заинлайнится? Получившийся амссемблерный код сравнивал?

Comment: Я в ассемблере не бум-бум =(

Comment: Это не исходники clang, а исходники libc++. Итераторы могут быть указателями. И даже если они не указатели, то не факт, что их можно заменить на указатели или что это даст прирост производительности.

Comment: Первая реализация не работает ни с какими указателями, а в зависимости от типа переданного итератора,  использует или rvalue ссылку итератора или , если это  указатель, то его копию(если быть кратким).  Почему в другой библиотеке  не эта реализация?...  Этот вопрос можно задать по всем реализациям....